# Given a polygon & line in It: Find position on line where to split the polygon with perpendicular line to get subpolygon with cetain area

Tags: python, geometry

Inputs:

- Polygon (you can imagine this as a street: long and relatively narrow)
- Line: the line is assumed to lie within the polygon and to run along the full length of the polygon
- Required Area: The area the resulting output sub-polygon must have

Outputs:

- Subpolygon of the input polygon with an area of the required area from input.

[Example image of inputs and outputs: input polygon (blue), input line (red), line where the polygon is cut to produce output polygon (green)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY30w.png)

The input polygon is cut into two pieces at some point along the given line, with a line that is (if possible) perpendicular to the line.

I hope its clear what I mean - it's already rather difficult to alone describe the problem.

I'm using the shapley geometry library (for python).
Polygons are described as a set of points that represent the outer boundary and optionally also sets of point that describe holes inside the polygon.
Lines are described as a list of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider a binary search along the red polyline.

1. Calculate the total length (`L`) of the red polyline (= sum of all
   segment lengths)
2. Assume we have a function that can calculate the point (`p`) and
   normal (`n`) corresponding to a value `v` along the polyline, where
   `0 <= v <= L`.
3. Assume we have a function that can calculate the result of splitting
   the input polygon given a line defined by a point `p` and direction
   vector `n`.
4. Perform a binary search, starting with `left = 0, right = L`, splitting the polygon at the line defined by `mid(left, right)` and comparing the resulting areas against the target.

Here's a sketch of the solution:

```
fn areaSearch(polygon, polyline, aTarget)

  left = 0
  right = length(polyline)

  while left < right
    mid = left + (right-left)/2;
    (p,n) = pointNormal(polyline, mid)
    (aLeft, aRight) = split(polygon, p, n)

    if aLeft eq aTarget or aRight eq aTarget return (p, n)

    if aLeft < aTarget
     right = mid
    else
     left = mid
```

`pointNormal` would look something like:

```
fn pointNormal(polyline, v) 
  for each segment of polyline
    len = len(segment)
    if v < len
      p = segment.start + v*unit(segment) 
      n = segment normal
      return (p, n)
    else
      v = v - len
```

There are a couple of issues with this approach:

1. It requires the splitting line to be perpendicular to a segment of the red polyline. It doesn't, for example, consider lines that bisect adjacent segments at endpoints.
2. For a given target there could be two possible solutions, one where the "left" polygon has the required area and another where the "right" polygon does. It's possible that a solution exists for one but not the other, given issue 1. The solution sketched above only consider the "left" polygon.